# Graph API for C#: BadGateway result when try to create a Team on Office 365

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I have been working since a couple of days into a Solution that creates a Team and Groups with a Site collection in SharePoint. I have gotten some error messages related with BadGateway when I tried to create a new Team into a Group.

This is the code that is throwing an Exception:

```
 var team = new Team
                {
                    MemberSettings = new TeamMemberSettings
                    {
                        AllowCreateUpdateChannels = true
                    },
                    MessagingSettings = new TeamMessagingSettings
                    {
                        AllowUserEditMessages = true,
                        AllowUserDeleteMessages = true
                    },
                    FunSettings = new TeamFunSettings
                    {
                        AllowGiphy = true,
                        GiphyContentRating = GiphyRatingType.Strict
                    }
                };

                await graphClient.Groups[groupid].Team
                    .Request()
                    .PutAsync(team);
```

The exception thrown is:

```
Code: BadGateway
Message: Failed to execute backend request.
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    request-id: a3ecc097-6969-4263-84dd-e6c3fd60bd03
    date: 2020-04-18T13:02:43
ClientRequestId: a3ecc097-6969-4263-84dd-e6c3fd60bd03
```

Some more comments:

1. User that executes is the Site Collection Admin (when this objects is initizialed)

```
var authManager = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager();
            ClientContext context = authManager.GetSharePointOnlineAuthenticatedContextTenant(AdminSiteUrl, username, pwd);
```

2. The Client Secret Id and the App registration in Azure has the following permissions:
   [image: App registrated permissions in Azure Active Directory]
3. The especific version that I am using to declare the Team object is Assembly Microsoft.Graph, Version=3.3.0.0 using Nuget. I have the same issue when I use 3.2.0.0

I know its possible to execute the same method using the REST API directly, but I am not sure if this new version (released some days ago has a bug). So, I would like to know how to fix this error or if I should move using REST API directly (If you have an example code, it would be great!!). Thank u!

Comment: I'm receiving the same response as above since yesterday (Apr 17th).  Creating a Team or Channel was working before.  Incidently MSFT released Graph API updates yesterday so presuming it could caused issues.  I'm waiting for a response from MSFT support to verify

Comment: MSFT must have fixed something as my app is now working

Comment: Hello, I am still getting the same error. I am using 3.3 DLL version. Are you using C# or rest api directly?

Comment: Using version 3.1,0 via c# - code similar to yours above, however I'm setting ODataType=null for each of the objects including the Team object itself.  IE 
var team = new GraphApi.Team
            {      
                MemberSettings = new GraphApi.TeamMemberSettings
                {
                    AllowCreateUpdateChannels = true,
                    ODataType = null
                } ...

Comment: Hello, I have downgrade to 3.1.0 via C#. I have answer this with fullcode :)Than you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Graph API SDK 3.1.0.  Try setting  ODataType = null within the team objects

```
            var team = new GraphApi.Team
            {      
                MemberSettings = new GraphApi.TeamMemberSettings
                {
                    AllowCreateUpdateChannels = true,
                    ODataType = null
                },
                MessagingSettings = new GraphApi.TeamMessagingSettings
                {
                    AllowUserEditMessages = true,
                    AllowUserDeleteMessages = true,
                    ODataType = null
                },
                FunSettings = new GraphApi.TeamFunSettings
                {
                    AllowGiphy = true,
                    GiphyContentRating = GraphApi.GiphyRatingType.Strict,
                    ODataType = null
                },
                ODataType = null
            };
```

Comment: Hello Phat, I am still getting the same error. Also, I have figured out that you are using Graph.Team. Is not it correct use  Microsoft.Graph.Team instead? Code: BadGateway
Message: Failed to execute backend request.
Inner error:
 AdditionalData:
 request-id: e2fd9062-b737-4acf-b82f-be0a113cb62a
 date: 2020-04-19T17:39:21
ClientRequestId: e2fd9062-b737-4acf-b82f-be0a113cb62a

Comment: GraphApi in my above code is an alias for the Microsoft.GraphApi, so it's the same

Comment: I've tested above using Microsoft.Graph .Net SDK v3.3.  There was originally an error with invalid ODataType for each of the elements.  Modifying to the following empty Team object was successful.
var team = new Team
 {
  ODataType = null
 };

Comment: If reverting to v3.1 or using the workaround I mentioned was successful, please mark this question as answered.  Additionally you can open an issue on the [Microsoft Graph .Net SDK issues list](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues).

Comment: Please open an issue (link in prior comment) and share steps to reproduce on the opened issue.