# System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)

Tags: c#

Im getting an exception

> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
> includeTaskCanceledExceptions)     at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken),  Exception:"Object reference not
> set to an instance of an object.

while trying to get the data. I have a like a list of 1000 items for each item I´m calling this:

```
      foreach(var item from list)
      {
           var result= getattributes(item.id);
      }
      private attributes getattributes(string id)
      {
       using (var client1 = new HttpClient())
        {
            client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new 
              AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", oneTimeAuth);
      try
        {
            string url = connectionDetails.BaseUrl;
            var deviceattribute = client1.GetStringAsync(url);
            deviceattribute.Wait();
            var deviceattributeResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<deviceattributes>(deviceattribute.Result);
            if(deviceattributeResult != null)
            {
                return deviceattributeResult;
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLog((int)Core.Enums.JobLogType.Error, $"Exception while getting I. {ex.StackTrace}");
        }
    }
    return null;

}
```

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The stack trace is telling you where the exception is being thrown, but not why. You haven't provided enough information for other people to be able to help you. Try outputting the whole exception (e.g. `ex.ToString()`) instead of `ex.StackTrace`, and see if that log message is more helpful.

Comment: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Response status code does not indicate success: 502 (Bad Gateway).)   ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 502 (Bad Gateway).  at system.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()     at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetStringAsyncCore(Task`1 getTask)     --- End of inner exception  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: Well, that's a server error.  502 is _usually_ out of your control if the backend was written properly.

Comment: Im trying to get data from Graph Api

Comment: Well, at least that gives you something new to search for, like https://stackoverflow.com/q/61463672/120955 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/61289733/120955